# memory allocation details using strcat

Tags: c++, c

I'm using following code to print strings.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  char s[100];
  while(1){
     char f[10000];
     cin>>s;
     strcat(f,s);
     cout<<f<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

in each iteration a new allocation of f character array is done.

input

```
a

b

c

d
```

I expected that the output would be like this:

```
a

b

c

d
```

but actual output is:

```
a

ab

abc

abcd
```

Why is this happening ? Though I'm declaring a new array in each iteration 
so why is this kind of output ??

Comment: `strcat` wants a NUL terminated string, initialize `s`, `char s[100] = {0};`, outside the loop.

Comment: It's actually pretty funny.  What you see happening is purely by luck.  You happened to get lucky that the first time you enter the loop f[0] was zero.  Then each time the loop is re-executing you happened to get lucky that the trash on the stack is simply the previous stack trash being reused.

Comment: @AlterMann That's not the problem.  What he really wants to do is `f[0] = 0;` right after he declares `f` inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because: undefined behavior.

You are not initializing the array. You're only declaring it. Just because you declare

```
 char f[10000];
```

Does not mean that it's going to be initialized to an empty array, automatically.

So, you get a declared array, containing random data.

At this point, you cannot expect to get any predictable behavior. The results you got would be one plausible outcome. But not the only one.

EDIT: Each time around the loop, the array ends up at the same place on the stack. The first time in, your operating system set up a new page, for the stack, cleared to 0. You strcat()ed your string to it. The next time around the loop, your old data, from the previous iteration, is still there. So, you strcat() more stuff, appending it to the end.